# Question about trajectories of a vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, cauchy-problem

Let $F:D\subset\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ a vector field of class $C^1$ in an open subset $U$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $p_0\in D$ is a point such that $F(p_0)=0$. I need to prove thar $F_t(p_0)=p_0$  and $dF_t=e^{tdF(p_0)}$.

Notation: $F_t(p)=\varphi(t,p)$ is the trajectory of $F$ passing through $p$.

I considered the Cauchy Problem

$$\begin{cases}
x'=F(x) \\
x(0)=p_0
\end{cases}$$

By definition, the solution is $\varphi(t,p)=F_t(p)$. Therefore,

$$dF_t(p_0)=F(F_t(p_0))
\\
\implies \left.dF_t(p_0)\right\vert_{t=0}=F(F_0(p_0))=F(p_0)=0
$$

So, $F_t(p)$ is constant (with respect of $p$). If I could find any point such that $F_t(\tilde{p})=p_0$, I would conclude that $F_t(p_0)=p_0$, but I didn't. Is there something obvius that I'm not seeing?

And I tried to build some Cauchy Problems to get to the second affirmative, but I didn't got it.

Comment: For the first question, $F_t(p_0)$ is from the definition the solution starting from $p_0$. Therefore as $F(p_0)=0$, the solution is just constant equal to $p_0$. For the second one, you could differentiate your Cauchy problem with respect to $p$ to get new equation for $\frac{\partial \phi(t,p)}{\partial p} $.

Comment: @M_S I didn't got to the second equation. Basically I only know that $d\left(\frac{d}{dt}F_t(p_0)\right)=dF(p_0)\cdot dF_t(p_0)$. How can I make the exponential term arises?

Comment: I now think that there's a typo in your question. Shouldn't you have $dF_t(p_0)=e^{tdF(p_0)}$? You would obtain then your exponential term straight from the ODE for $dF_t(p_0)$